# How can I assign a return value from a procedure to a new variable in Firebird?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, firebird

This is the procedure I am calling:

```
set term # ;
create procedure f_rating(budget int)
 returns (final_result varchar(5))
as
begin
 if (budget <= 500000) then final_result = 'LOW';
 else if (budget <= 850000) then final_result = 'MID';
 else if (budget <= 1200000) then final_result = 'HIGH';
 else if (budget > 1200000) then final_result = 'ULTRA';
end #
commit work #
```

I am calling it inside a trigger:

```
set term # ;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_department_rating_insert for department_tester after insert
as
begin
 select result from f_rating(NEW.budget) into :temp_rating; 
 update department_rating
    set occurrences = occurrences + 1
    where rating = temp_rating;
end # 
commit work #
```

I'm pretty sure its probably a dumb syntax error but I can't figure it out.

Comment: If you are using Firebird 3, then you should consider replacing that stored procedure with a function.

Answer (score 1):

The `f_rating` is not selectable stored procedure (it doesn't have `SUSPEND` in it) so the syntax to call it is `EXECUTE PROCEDURE <name> RETURNING_VALUES(<params>);`, ie

```
set term # ;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_department_rating_insert for department_tester after insert
as
begin
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_rating(NEW.budget) RETURNING_VALUES(:temp_rating); 
 update department_rating
    set occurrences = occurrences + 1
    where rating = temp_rating;
end # 
commit work #
```